# Reactive navigation error: The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Dict"} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am a beginner of react native. After reading the reactive navigation basics, I'm trying to build my personal app. However, I have a difficulty of navigation to another components.

I only have the following components:

- app.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Image } from 'react-native';
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer, StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Dict from './dict';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ height: '100%' }}>
      <View style={{
        height: '15%', backgroundColor: 'powderblue', flexDirection:'row'
      }} />
      <Text>This is a test</Text>
      <Button title="Go to Dictionary" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dict')}/>
    </View>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

- dict.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';


function Dict () {
  return (
    <Text>Hello, I am your cat!</Text>
  );
}

export default Dict;
```

When I click the button *Go to Dictionary*, I've received the following error message:
**The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Dict"} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'Dict'?**

What I want to achieve is jump to the dictionary page via a button click. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your `Dict` screen in your Navigator, try this:

```js
export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Dict"
          component={Dict}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: This ^^ is the correct answer. It's not finding "Dict" because you haven't defined a "Dict" route (Screen) within your Stack

Comment: Thank you, my problem is solved. That means, if I want to navigate to any other component, I must put it as a Stack.Screen element? Thank you for your answer again!

Comment: @warrenbuffering. If I understand you correctly, NavigationContainer itself is a router, correct? Thank you!

Comment: The `NavigationContainer` is responsible for managing your app state and linking your top-level navigator to the app environment : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/

Comment: And for the screens it could help you: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#api-definition